# How to find out if a string of words fall in fibonacci pattern or not

Tags: java, string, logic, fibonacci

**Question :** To verify whether a string given as input, the length of the words, fall in a *fibonacci pattern* or not, i.e. the word's length is sum of lengths of two words before it.

A word is composed of letters only. E.g. ra!hul is 2 words separated by !.

The input can have any number of words. All inputs must have atleast 3 words.
For example `I AM, RON!!` is in follows the pattern (`I`, `AM`, `RON`), while `Is IT HERs!E`(`Is`, `IT`, `HERs`, `E`) does not, as 4th element should have length 6.

Output should be like if all the words inputted fall in fibonacci pattern, then it should output `YES` in the end after checking all the words, if it doesn't fall in fibonacci pattern at any part of input, it should output `NO`, without further assessing henceforth ending the run too.

**My issue :** i did write a code, it constantly outputs as NO, i don't get it where my logic goes wrong, but i feel i err just after the switch loop, do modify/suggest , alternative and better methods are too welcome. Here's my code :

```
public class Holla {
      static int j=-1,a,b,c;
       public static void main(String[] args) {
               Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            String h=s.nextLine();
            int i=0,x=0;
            while(i<h.length())
            {
                if(Character.isLetter(h.charAt(i)))
                     x++;
                else
                {
                    while(x>0)
               out: {
                       j++;
                        switch (j) 
                        {
                            case 0:
                                a=x;
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                b=x;
                                break;
                            default:
                                c=x;
                        }
                        if((j==0)||(j==1))
                              break out;
                            if (c==(a+b))
                                {
                                   a=b;
                                    b=c;
                                    j=1;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    System.out.println("NO");
                                    System.exit(0);
                                }
                    }
                    x=0;
                }
                i++;
            }
           System.out.println("YES");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any debugging performed on this code.  Please [edit] your question to show us what your debugging has uncovered, as well as a specific question about a specific line of code.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: _"i feel i have made the question details too wordy, so if you wish you can edit and make it as concise as possible"_ did you really just write a question, and ask us to improve your own question?

Comment: Explaining your problem even more explicitly is not the same as debugging.  You should be able to point at no more than five lines of code and explain why those five lines are not doing what you expect them to.  Until you do that, I will not be removing my downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make more use of Java standard library.

First, let's assume you have input: `String input`.

To make life easier, let's split it into list of element words, each separated by something different than a normal letter:

```
String pattern = "^[a-zA-Z]";
String tokens[] = input.split(pattern);
Predicate<String> filterNonEmpty = a -> !a.isEmpty();
List<String> words =
    Arrays.asList(tokens).stream().filter(filterNonEmpty).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

All right, now we have the words, so it's time to run the "Fibonacci checker" (that is, we check for every word if its length is equal to sum of length of two previous ones):

```
if (words.size() < 3) { .... } // handle edge case specified in question

// grab lengths of first & second word
int len1 = words.get(0).length();
int len2 = words.get(1).length();

// now iterate over remaining words
for (int i = 2; i < words.size; ++i) {
    String newWord = words.get(i);
    int newLen = newWord.length();
    if (newLen != len1 + len2) {
        // word at index [i] does not have "Fibonacci size"
        return false;
    } else {
        // everything good, we need to move the lengths
        len1 = len2;
        len2 = newLen;
    }
}
// all the words had "Fibonacci size"
return true;
```

btw. 
Be aware that this code will return `true` for words with lengths: `1, 3, 4, 7, 11` what is not a Fibonacci sequence (as the start elements are not `0 & 1` / `1 & 1`).